# Taxonomy terms listed by content type

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have a taxonomy and two content types that can be associated with a term. How can I display the content types as different lists (hopefully separate zones) on the term page?

For example I have the taxonomy genres with content types books and movies. On the page for the term Crime I would like one list for crime movies and one for crime books.

I am a front end developer so c# code would have to be easy to plug in if necessary. I also would love to do this without resorting to front end sorting so that the solution performs better and is more scalable.

Comment: Did you try to use projections? The term page itself will show everything, but you should be able to build your own with a simple query with a couple filters.

Comment: I tried creating queries but the limitation of not being able to do dynamic taxonomy queries would make it not very scalable. With 20 taxonomy terms I would have to create 40 queries with 20 layouts just for these pages.

Comment: You could do taxonomy queries based on querystring tokens, with some small modifications of the existing taxonomy term filter.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Bertrand. I found [this project](https://github.com/Jetski5822/Orchard.Taxonomies.ProjectionFilters) on Github that seems to be doing what I want to do but I can't get it to work. That's off topic for this question and I'm not sure if it's unfinished code or that I just don't know how to use it, so I'll start a topic on codeplex.

Comment: Looks like it, yes. The author, Nick, is usually useful so I'm sure you'll be able to get that working...